# Xpath for checkbox element by locating it's following label element by value

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, wicket

I have been working for quite a while on this and still haven't found an answer specific to my problem in stackoverflow or from experimenting with the Xpath myself. I am quite inexperienced so I alpogise if this is a simple problem but I would really appreciate any help.

I am working with Selenium to test a web app that uses Wicket. I need the Xpath to the checkbox that correlates to the respective label. This is because I need to be able to enter the value shown on the label and for it to find the relevant checkbox based on the label text such as "001", as the checkbox ids do not match the values.

Mockup below shows the checkboxes and their corresponding labels;

[image: mockup]

The corresponding HTML is show below;

```
<span wicket:id="excludeDepotCheckBox" id="excludeDepotCheckBox5">

  <input name="adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="0" id="excludeDepotCheckBox5-adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox_0">
  <label for="excludeDepotCheckBox5-adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox_0">001</label>

  <br>

<input name="adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="excludeDepotCheckBox5-adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox_1">
  <label for="excludeDepotCheckBox5-adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox_1">009</label>

  <br>

</span>
```

Another problem I also face is that the Xpath must include the fact that it is inside the span shown in the html as there are 3 other groups of checkboxes on the page with the same values so it must be specific for each span for example:

```
id="excludeDepotCheckBox5"
```

I have tried the following Xpaths to no avail;

```
//span[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5' and contains(., '009')]"

"//*[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5' and ./label/text()='009']/preceding-sibling::*[@name='adminPreferenceSection:excludeDepotCheckBox']

//*[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5' and ./label/text()='009']/preceding-sibling::input[1]"
```

Again I aplogise if it is a simple syntax/understanding problem but I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "preceding-sibling" is so error-prone (it will break as soon as the HTML structure changes a little bit), here's a more stable variant (wrapped for legibility):

```
//span[@id = 'excludeDepotCheckBox5']//input[
    @id = //span[@id = 'excludeDepotCheckBox5']//label[normalize-space() = '001']/@for
]
```

Comment: This is a great answer works perfectly and I really appreciate that it's more stable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below xpaths:

**1-** For **checking the checkbox related to label '001'**:

```
//span[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5']/label[.='001']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

**2-** For **checking the checkbox related to label '009'**:

```
//span[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5']/label[.='009']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

**NOTE: It will check for the 'input' element which is the first preceeding sibling of label element with exact innerHTML/text as '001' or '009' under a span element with id='excludeDepotCheckBox5'.**

Comment: This works great for one set of checkboxes but as I had several sets of checkboxes with the same values I had to use arisalexis answer as it included how to choose which set of checkboxes to choose from. Although I had to make a change to his as it selected the previous checkbox rather than the corresponsing checkbox.

Comment: Okay.. I have edited my answer above. Please check if it serves your purpose now. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Thanks Subh this works perfectly now too, works with or without span included

Answer (score 1):

//*[@id='excludeDepotCheckBox5']/label[contains(text(),'001')]//preceding-sibling::input[1]

Comment: This answer was great I just had to add [1] after input to make sure it got the corresponding checkbox and not the one before that.